# Greeting Anniversary Celebrators

Tags: punctuation

Do you write " Happy Anniversary Jane & Henry!" or "Happy anniversary, Jane & Henry!"

Comment: You write it either way, because it doesn't matter and they won't notice. All they'll remember is that you thought of them and wished them well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you use a comma to set off a direct address from the rest of a sentence. For example:

- Happy Anniversary, Jane & Henry!
- Where are you going, Dad?
- Susan, I need to talk to you.
- Mr. Smith, the doctor will see you now.

[Grammarbook](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp) has a good list of rules for comma use. The one this question pertains to is Rule #5.